# Adding emoji to textbox via click but no color

Tags: excel, vba

I am adding with this code to my `TextBoxSafety` a Star to current position. But internet says the code which i am using `ChrW(&H2B50)` is a yellow star - which i also want. But when i click on the `Label9`, it apears in colorless mode so black. How can i solve it, that i have it with color. Also tried with another codes/emojies

```
Private Sub Label9_Click()
    Dim currentText As String
    Dim cursorPosition As Integer
    
    currentText = TextBox1SafetyText
    
    cursorPosition = TextBoxSafety.SelStart
    
    TextBoxSafety.Text = Left(currentText, cursorPosition) & ChrW(&H2B50) & Mid(currentText, cursorPosition + 1)
    
    TextBoxSafety.SelStart = cursorPosition + 1
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be the font that defines this. Try changing the font for that particular cell and see if that makes a difference.